# discord.js get last message in channel as global variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, global-variables

I'm currently programming a discord bot with Voice to text processing, therefore I need a global msg variable, to access commands like `msg.reply`, `msg.channel.send`, and `msg.guild` for my functions to use.

I don't want to call my function every time a new message was posted and don’t want to pass `msg` via the function parameters.

Is there a way to extract the last/current `msg` out of following function to make it available globally (in every function)?

```
discordClient.on('message', async (msg) => {
    try {
        if (!('guild' in msg) || !msg.guild) return; // prevent private messages to bot
        await process_command(msg);
        } catch (e) {
        console.log('discordClient message: ' + e)
        await msg.reply('Error#180: Something went wrong, try again or contact the developers if this keeps happening.');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I strongly disagree with the premise of the question (of using a global variable), and I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do with this global variable nor why you don't want to call a function multiple times nor why you don't want to pass an object as a parameter, is there a reason you can't just

```
var lastMsg;

/* ... */

discordClient.on('message', async (msg) => {
    try {
        if (!msg.guild) return; // prevent private messages to bot
        lastMsg = msg;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('discordClient message: ' + e)
        await msg.reply('Error#180: Something went wrong, try again or contact the developers if this keeps happening.');
    }
});
```

Here `lastMsg` is a global variable, which means every time anyone sends a message to the bot in any guild, it will be overwritten with that new message. If you're doing this, **you should be very sure that this is the desired behaviour**. In general, especially for asynchronous computation, storing intermediate data in global variables is a known as a *very very bad idea*.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know any other options to access msg.reply or only extract certain parts of msg like channel and guild ? to be globally available, if that would reduce complexity of this object. I guess it would be the best to create a new msg object which just includes these functions (same structure as msg) and make this globally available instead the entire msg object

Comment: No, you shouldn't have a global variable for this at all. Every time someone sends a message to a guild, it will overwrite your message object. This means, for example, if two people send messages to two different guilds at almost the exact same time, then the first message will be almost immediately overwritten by the second message. Even if you process the first message, `lastMsg.reply()` will reply in the second guild. Why do you want to "reduce the complexity of this object"? What is the object in question? Remember that the `msg` object is passed by reference when you call a function.

Comment: I want to use "process_command(msg);" function not only for the async (msg) function but
 in my asnychronous speech processing function aswell.
Therefore I also need the current msg object to reply or get the guild, channel id etc.

Comment: @jackobhusein I assume that means, upon receiving a certain command, you want the bot listen to a user, then do some speech processing, then send a response. In that case, I might recommend creating a new object that holds the received `msg`, then writing the audio data to that object as well. Once you finish recording the audio, you can send the entire object to the processing function, and you'll be able to process the audio and then reply to the correct channel. I will note that, due to the nature of your bot, there is a whole lot of other stuff that can go wrong.

Comment: Hmm its not that simple. Its more like I have a certain command set like "join, help,..."
in my process_command function. I want ot access them not only through writing in a channel, but through speech processing aswell.

So the basic sequence would be like this in short:
1: user wrote *join
2. bot processes command and joins channel
3. user SAYS" help"
4. bot processes command and post help msg to channel
5. user wrote "help"
4. bot processes command and post help msg to channel

Comment: @jackobhusein Well, again, that poses the issue of which channel the bot should post to. For example, assume your guild has 4 text channels. You have the bot join a voice channel, then say "help". Where should the bot post? Presumably, you would have the bot post in the same channel as the one where you typed "*join", but that's not clear. If we assume that's the case, then the recommendation I made above should suffice, maybe with a bit of modification (if you want it to take more than one voice command before disconnecting; however, it might misinterpret conversation as a command).